# Testing my operators, what do I need to set up first?

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to test one of my operator.
For this I inspire my code from :

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/tests/operators/test_python_operator.py

I copy pasted the code and tried to execute it.
I happen to have an exception generated by the create_session method from airflow.

Here is the full stack.

```
../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:552: OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

cls = <class 'tests.include.operators.test_feature_flip_operator.TestShortCircuitOperator'>

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()

        with create_session() as session:
>           session.query(DagRun).delete()

__class__  = <class 'tests.include.operators.test_feature_flip_operator.TestShortCircuitOperator'>
cls        = <class 'tests.include.operators.test_feature_flip_operator.TestShortCircuitOperator'>
session    = <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x7f1d0c84b410>

tests/include/operators/test_feature_flip_operator.py:52: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3700: in delete
    delete_op.exec_()
../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py:1694: in exec_
    self._do_exec()
../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py:1922: in _do_exec
    self._execute_stmt(delete_stmt)
../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py:1699: in _execute_stmt
    self.result = self.query._execute_crud(stmt, self.mapper)
../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3367: in _execute_crud
    return conn.execute(stmt, self._params)
../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:988: in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:287: in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1107: in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1253: in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1473: in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:398: in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:152: in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
../.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1249: in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.pysqlite.SQLiteDialect_pysqlite object at 0x7f1d0ce77190>
cursor = <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f1d0c8fa960>
statement = 'DELETE FROM dag_run', parameters = ()
context = <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.base.SQLiteExecutionContext object at 0x7f1d0c781890>

    def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: dag_run
E       [SQL: DELETE FROM dag_run]
E       (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

context    = <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.base.SQLiteExecutionContext object at 0x7f1d0c781890>
cursor     = <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f1d0c8fa960>
parameters = ()
self       = <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.pysqlite.SQLiteDialect_pysqlite object at 0x7f1d0ce77190>
statement  = 'DELETE FROM dag_run'
```

Do I have to set up a local database or something ?
I struggle to find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

airflow unit tests code (e.g., `https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/tests/operators/test_python_operator.py`) is used by CI to cover airflow code.

It requires some setup and certain steps to run airflow unit tests. Take `https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/.travis.yml` for example, you will need:

1. run `https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/scripts/ci/ci_before_install.sh` to install required modules and make sure docker/docker-swarm are installed.
2. run `https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/scripts/ci/ci_run_airflow_testing.sh` to build container image from current branch with given build config (uses sqlite as default db, run against docker as default), then kick off unit tests via `nosetests`.

You can tweak `https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/scripts/ci/in_container/run_ci_tests.sh#L49` to run a subset of unit tests instead of all of them (costs 20min+).